# Node.js process and exit codes not showing up

Tags: javascript, node.js, signals

sig.js

```
process.on("exit", function(code){
  process.stdout.write("it was: " + code);
});

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("times up");
}, 30000);
```

if I then run

`nohup node sig.js &`

and let the clock run out, I get the expected `nohup.out` file

```
it was: 0
```

but if I use `kill -SIGINT <process id>` then I get a `nohup.out` file that is completely empty. Based on the docs https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit I am expecting *something*... What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linked docs:

> This event is only emitted when Node.js exits explicitly by
>   process.exit() or implicitly by the event loop draining.

The process is killed before the exit event is fired when you send a SIGINT.

You need to explicitly listen for the SIGINT event:

```
process.on("SIGINT", function () {
  //graceful shutdown
  process.exit();
});
```

This will catch the SIGINT and perform a graceful shutdown, which will force it through your expected code.